# C++: how to alternate between types if they have to be hardcoded?

Tags: c++, opencv

Hello stackoverflow community.

I'm using the OpenCV Mat object and I want to use their .at(y,x) function. Suppose we are in the situation where you know that type will either be double or unsigned short, but you don't want to duplicate your code to account for that.

Eg you have:

```
img.at<double>(y,x);
```

or

```
img.at<unsigned short>(y,x);
```

Instead of having to write both of those lines inside either a switch or if statement, is it possible to do something like this instead?

```
type a;
some code to set a as double or unsigned short;
img.at<a>(y,x);
```

Comment: `using type = int;` and `img.at<type>(x, y)`? What does it mean _some code to set a as double or unsigned short_? How do you decide?

Comment: That's what templates are made for. (Note that if the condition whether `double` or `unsigned short` is used is not compile time constant then you'll need an if / switch at some point.)

Comment: You can't do that. But you can: 1) create a template function, and a switch to call it with the correct template. 2) convert the unsigned short to double and use just a function that works on double. Eventually convert back to unsigned short. 3) Work only with OpenCV functions (never use `at`) that deal automatically with this 4) Have a better interface and expect just a single type

Comment: There is a better way to do this than the answer that is mentioned in the "duplicate"

Comment: @Ankur what exactly? I can just remove the duplicate if needed

Comment: Cast the `Mat` to the `Mat_`  template class and then use indexing to access the elements.

Comment: @Ankur And exactly to what template do you cast? You still need a switch, and you still need two different functions, one for `Mat1d` and one for `Mat1w` (assuming you know the number of channels, obviously)

Comment: The whole function that is performing the operations on the either uchar or double matrix needs to be templated function.

Comment: @Ankur sorry I was busy.... Having `foo(Mat_<T> m){m(0,0) = 3;}` or having `bar(Mat m){m.at<T>(0,0) = 3}` is exactly equivalent. In both cases you need a template function, and a switch to select the correct template. I can't see how this is a _better way_. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Miki If the function is supposed to return some value of type of the matrix then the `bar` version won't work, but yeah if the function is about mutating the mat in place then there is no difference.

Comment: @Ankur no. The bar version works as good as foo.

Comment: @Miki What would be the return type of bar if we need to compute the minimum value of all the values in the Mat?

Comment: Aside that you would use "cv::minMaxLoc" and the min value is always double (for 1 channel images)... you can simply return T: "T bar(Mat m){T value = ...; return value;}. @Ank